# Popular blog not making money?

Tags: google-adsense, blog, marketing, revenue, money

I am running a popular blog magazine over 8 years, has great traffic about 500,000 impressions and 20,000 clicks monthly.

The only source of revenue I use is Adsense but it is not even bringing $100.

How do I monetize this properly (please give me some ideas)?

I am quite perplexed here with that much amount of organic traffic, I am not converting. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your site looks nice, however, a quick review and I do not see enough ads in higher value positions on the page. Look for good adsense optimization tips from credible sources. I suggest starting with Google.

Comment: I am not sure i can post here, but site i am talking about  is http://www.corpocrat.com. I believe without having a look at the actual site, people cannot give any ideas, like flying blind.

Comment: I specifically removed your link to prevent your question from being closed. You are right about people seeing your site. At first blush, it appears that you can use more ads placed in key spots on the page. I suggest starting with Googles recommendations on ad placement. That should make a real difference for you. It is about advertisers bidding on your site. You have to cover topics high value advertisers want to see. Ad size and placement is key too. Otherwise, the bids remain lower. Cheers!!

Comment: I would have tried to close this question as "too broad" because you're asking for ways to make money for an online blog. My apologizes if I sound ridiculous but one idea is that you can post paper signs on posts located at street corners asking for donations to your blog to try to make money.

Comment: I believe this is not a public forum rather one for webmasters. I believe there is nothing wrong with asking other webmasters on how to monetize a site, who had similar experience. I dont want to be mean here: The topic i started is not asking for money, rather asking for ideas to monetize. I am sorry may be i have come to the wrong place to help. I should be posting in warrior or digitalpoint forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are missing something big time, but you need to get us some insights about it.

You need to look for paid posts, some advertisers and similar to get more revenue from that blog. That's up to you and your negotiating techniques. Bigger money lies in that kind of approach then in adsense. Adsense gives you money if someone clicks on the advertising. Well... I have adblocker installed and I don't see any advertisements.

So basically, you need to conect with advertisers directly so you can put their banners or paid posts. You need to provide them insights about your impressions and clicks.